# Flutter: Provider: ListView not repainting after notifyListener()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I've seen this question asked many times with no answer. I want to get to the bottom of it. I literally cannot move forward in my app without this working...

Why does Provider fail to trigger ListView repaint after a notifyListeners call is made.

Simplified Code Example (The data bucket):

```
class TheData extends ChangeNotifier {
   List<ListTile> data = [
      ListTile(title: Text('A')),
   ];

   addTile() {
      data.add(ListTile(title: Text('B')));
      notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

The screen using TheData:

```
class TheScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TheScreenState createState() => TheScreenState();
}

class TheScreenState extends State<TheScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TheData>(
       builder: (ctx, _theData, _) {
           print('rebuilding count = ${_theData.data.length}');
           return ListView(
              children: _theData.data,
           );
       }
    );
  }
}
```

Let's assume TheData class is provided correctly above this screen in the widget tree and that I triggered 'addTile()'. The print shows that there are now 2 elements in 'data', but the ListView does not change.

This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this made a difference or if it is less efficient... However, using ListView.builder() fixes the problem:

```
class TheScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TheScreenState createState() => TheScreenState();
}

class TheScreenState extends State<TheScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TheData>(
       builder: (ctx, _theData, _) {
           print('rebuilding count = ${_theData.data.length}');
           return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _theData,data.length,
              itemBuilder: (c, i) => _theData.data[i],
           );
       }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. The issue is that Flutter uses immutable objects. So although the underlying data changes, ListView does not notice the need to repaint because the reference didn't change